# data.frame and get_elev_points. Error in locations$elevation[idx_s[i]:idx_e[i]] <- unlist(resp$height) : replacement has length zero

Tags: r, elevation, elevatr

I am trying to use the function get_elevation_points in a data frame, but keep getting the same error:

Thanks!

```
> #get the API key : et an API Key from https://mapzen.com/developers. Since elevatr will search the environment for the appropriate key, 
> #it is suggested that you store this in your .Renviron file. To do this:
> 
> require(sf) 
  require(sp)
> 
> cat("mapzen_key=mapzen-XXXXXXX\n", file =
> file.path(normalizePath("~/"), ".Renviron"), 
>     append = TRUE) mydata <- st_as_sf(x = Coordinates_alt, 
>                         coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"),
>                         crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

> 

> coordinates(Coordinates_alt) <- cbind(Coordinates_alt$Longitude ,
> Coordinates_alt$Latitude) proj4string(Coordinates_alt) =
> CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0") 
> 
> require(elevatr)
> 
> prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
> 
> mydata1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(df, proj4string = CRS(prj_dd), data
> = df)
> 
> head(mydata1)
> 
> df_elev <- get_elev_point(mydata1, prj = prj_dd, src = "mapzen")
```

> df_elev <- get_elev_point(df, prj = prj_dd, src = "mapzen") Error in
>   locations$elevation[idx_s[i]:idx_e[i]] <- unlist(resp$height) :
>   replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message: src 'mapzen'
>   is deprecated and will cease to function after 
>               2018-01-31 due to shutdown of Mapzen; Use 'epqs' instead for US 
>               locations. Still searching for a global elevation service 
>               replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay in responding.  I am not terribly active on SO, but given the few `elevatr` questions I will be!

The issue you are having is that the `src = "mapzen"`, is an old source as all of the Mapzen services have been shut down.  If your coordinates are in the US, you can use the `src = "epqs"`, if they are outside of the US, you can use `src = "aws"` but depending on how many points and the extent of your bounding box that may take some time.  Also be sure to read the docs for `elevatr::get_elev_point()` as there is some additional information in there about setting the z value for the `aws` source.  Something like `elevatr::get_elev_point(mydata1, prj = prj_dd, src = "aws", z = 5)`  will be quick(ish) but resolution of the source raster data is pretty coarse.  You can change z (up to 14) but higher values will add time to the download depending, again, on the extent of your coordinates.